# Issues in invoking backdoor function for android using calabash tests

Tags: java, android, ruby, calabash

I am facing an issue when invoking a method of an android application through back door function.

In our project we are using backdoor for logging an event, simulating the hardware event using an calabash function called `backdoor`. This function is getting invoked but is failing in `perform_action` function as below

```
undefined method `perform_action' for #<Object:0x253ea38> (NoMethodError).
```

This backdoor is used to hook an application function  and we can use to our test cases to check response , make the settings using backdoor delegation

I think I am wrong in calling the passing the parameter to backdoor, could u please let me how to invoke. I have tried these statements and have failed in invoking.

I am using calabash-android 0.4.18 and had imported this function.

In My apk my sample java file is like this

```
public class sample {

    public boolean isDemoModel()
    {
            Log.d("Vageesh","Vageesh to test backboor");
            return true;
    }
}
```

In my script I tried to invoke using below ways and has failed for NoMethod error

```
backdoor('isDemoModel()','')
backdoor("'isDemoModel()'","")
backdoor("adb shell am broadcast -a sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend.isDemoModel",'')
```

Could any one please provide input on how an application function could be called. In IoS it is direct call like `backdoor('isDemoModel()','')`.

Regards

Vageesh

Comment: Just checking here, is there a particular reason why you are using version 0.4.18?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation about backdoors](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/working-with/backdoors/) the return type has to be void or String. Maybe that fixes your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a backdoor call is `backdoor(<name>, [args*])`. Don't use the parentheses.

`backdoor("isDemoModel")` is the correct way  of invoking the method in your example

Oh, and yes, you will need to update your calabash-android version.

Answer (score 0):

Your backdoor method has to be exposed as a public method in either an activity or the Application context.
E.g.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

     public void isDemoModel(){
        Log.d("Vageesh","Vageesh to test backboor");
        return true;
     }
}
```